# VBScript: how to set values from recordset to string

Tags: vbscript, string, recordset

This is probably a beginner question, but how do you set a recordset to a string variable?

Here is my code:

```
Function getOffice (strname, uname) 

strEmail = uname
WScript.Echo "email: " & strEmail 
Dim objRoot : Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Dim objDomain : Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & objRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
Dim cn : Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim cmd : Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT physicalDeliveryOfficeName FROM '" & objDomain.ADsPath & "' WHERE mail='" & strEmail & "'"
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1
cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 300
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

Dim objRS : Set objRS = cmd.Execute

  WScript.Echo objRS.Fields(0)

Set cmd = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set objRoot = Nothing

Dim arStore 

Set getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)

Set objRS = Nothing

End function
```

When I try to run the function, it throws an error "vbscript runtime error: Type mismatch"
I presume this means it can't set the string variable with a recordset value.

How do I fix this problem?

---

I just tried

if IsNull(objRS.Fields(0).Value) = TRUE then 
getOFfice = "noAD" 
else 
getOFfice = objRS.Fields(0).VAlue 
end if

And that throws a different error ADODB.Field: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has been deleted.  Requested operation requires a current record.

Comment: Set getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)
cannot be right - only objects are set and you are dealing with strings. You should also test first for eof and bof for the recordset.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
getOffice = objRS.getString
```

This will return the entire recordset as a tab delimited string.

Answer (score 2):

Set is only used for objects, it cannot be used on simple variables like strings.
Try this: (it also makes sure the recordset is not empty)

```
If objRS.RecordCount <> 0 Then
  getOffice = CStr(objRS.Fields(0))
Else
  getOffice = ""
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Cstr(objRS.Fields(0))
```

Comment: Says Invalid use of Null: 'CStr'

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this:

Set getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)

to this:

getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)

Comment: The WScript.Echo line.. 

getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)
WScript.Echo getOffice

thanks

Comment: Aah...in that case I suspect the null error that you mention above is a clue. What do you get from 
WScript.Echo VarType(objRS.Fields(0)

Comment: Hmm..  WScript.Echo VarType(objRS.Fields(0)) outputs "1"

Comment: I just googled it and means "Null".  ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: Then my guess is that you aren't actually getting anything back from your query.

Answer (score 0):

It's been my experience that the various ways of returning data from a DB call are often times very dependent on the method/driver used to access the data (e.g. ODBC, ADO, ADO.NET, ODP.NET, OleDB, etc.) Some need ToString(), GetString(), a cast, or some other variant of that.

Comment: This is an ADSI query.  I'm not sure how to get the string from this object..  any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that right after I'd posted my first response. But it still seems you're using ADO, so I would expect it to behave similarly. You might try calling MoveNext() on the Recordset prior to trying to read from it.

Comment: Or maybe objRS.Fields.Item(0)... It's been awhile since I used ADO; I'm rusty.

Comment: I thought about MoveNext, but he is trying to access the Fields collection which I think should be populated regardless of what record the pointer is on.

Comment: I tried the item() and it threw a different error saying it doesn't support that method.  I did do value and it threw me another bizaare error

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up adding "On Error Resume Next" to the top and it just skips the null errors.

although I wish there was an easier way to handle NULL values in vbscript.

thanks for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your recordset isn't empty? Normally you'd want to check first before you started doing anything. Not knowing anything else about what it needs to do, I might suggest something like this:

```
Function getOffice (strname, uname) 

strEmail = uname
WScript.Echo "email: " & strEmail 
Dim objRoot : Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Dim objDomain : Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & objRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
Dim cn : Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim cmd : Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT physicalDeliveryOfficeName FROM '" & objDomain.ADsPath & "' WHERE mail='" & strEmail & "'"
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1
cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 300
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

Dim objRS : Set objRS = cmd.Execute

If Not objRS.BOF Then objRS.Move First
If Not objRS.EOF Then 
  If Not IsNull(objRS.Fields(0)) and objRS.Fields(0) <> "" Then  WScript.Echo cStr(objRS.Fields(0))
End If

Set cmd = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set objRoot = Nothing

Dim arStore 

Set getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)

Set objRS = Nothing

End function
```

Obviously there are many ways of checking for an empty recordset, and checking for nulls, etc. but here's one way that may work.